# something is wrong with onChildAdded() within my Listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a chat app using firebase, have created a `Listener` that responds to add items in the database, as a result of an added item, all user should be getting a toast message, for some reason I am meeting the following problem.

Only the using phone that is being used to add messages,  get the toast, whereas the others don't. see attached code.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    //here should start the listener

    mChildRefrence.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String ItemKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            String msg = dataSnapshot.child("new_message").getValue(String.class);
            String senderName = dataSnapshot.child("senderName").getValue(String.class);
            String senderUid = dataSnapshot.child("senderUid").getValue(String.class);
            String receiverUid = dataSnapshot.child("receiverUid").getValue(String.class);
            String receiverName = dataSnapshot.child("receiverName").getValue(String.class);
            int seen = dataSnapshot.child("seen").getValue(Integer.class);
            // String timeMsgSent = dataSnapshot.child("timeMsgSent").getValue(String.class);

            boolean inserted = msgTable.insertData(ItemKey, senderName, senderUid, receiverName, receiverUid, msg,  seen, "timestamp");
            if (inserted)
                Log.d("test data", "info has been inserted");
            else
                Log.d("test data", "info has not been inserted");

            count++;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), count+"   "+msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Does the message show up in the database tab in your Firebase console? `https://console.firebase.google.com`

Comment: yes it does...@Frank van Puffelen

Comment: Be sure to implement `onCancelled()` of the listener to detect cases where the user doesn't have permission to read the data. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/22652/detect-errors-when-reading-data-on-android#t=201610130915072703509

Comment: not sure how the onCancelled helps,  it like randomly sends a notification like new Items have been added...@ Frank van Puffelen